# phpCAS::setDebug() is deprecated in favor of phpCAS::setLogger()

Tags: php, laravel, cas, phpcas

```
phpCAS::setDebug() is deprecated in favor of phpCAS::setLogger()
```

I got this error today, and I can't seem to find in what file phpCAS::setDebug() is used, anyone know how I can fix it?

[image: phpCAS::setDebug() is deprecated]

I tried downgrade apereo/phpcas to 1.3.8 (`composer require apereo/phpcas:1.3.8`), my friend that managed the server haven't tried it yet so I'm not sure

Source: https://github.com/subfission/cas/issues/93

[image: composer.json]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: https://github.com/subfission/cas/issues/93

I tried to downgrade apereo/phpcas from 1.3.9 to 1.3.8 and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment `trigger_error('phpCAS::setDebug() is deprecated in favor of phpCAS::setLogger().', E_USER_DEPRECATED);` in /vendor/apereo/phpcas/source/CAS.php

Comment: whilst this _will_ suppress your error it's not good to modify vendor files. running a composer update will overwrite this. a better solution would be to find where the deprecated call is and rectify that or notify the package maintainer if it's a vendor